# Suspend all desktop activity like Snipping Tool

Tags: java, desktop, suspend

I'm wondering how the snipping tool software on Windows is able to suspend the desktop activity. By this I mean that if I'm playing a game with moving objects or a video on youtube, they stop moving. It's like the video is paused even though it isn't.

I'm looking for a way to duplicate this effect, preferably in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't actually "suspend" activity - it simply captures a screenshot and freezes it until you make a selection. You can do a similar thing in Java by using the [Robot.createScreenCapture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) method to capture the screen and display this image in a full-screen window (see [Frame.setUndecorated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29)).

Comment: +1, but why use an undecorated frame when there is `JWindow`?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: You're absolutely right, I had forgotten about `JWindow`.